# Invoking a webservice from another webservice?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jax-ws, ejb-3.0

I have two Java web services deployed on Glassfish server using Netbeans 7.2.1, both services are inside the same web application. I am trying to invoke webservice2 from webservice1 and this is the code:

```
ebank.Customer_Service service = new ebank.Customer_Service();
ebank.Customer port = service.getCustomerPort();
port.getData();
```

However I get error saying:

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Customer
  location: package ebank
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a runtime or compile time error? Why did you add the ejb-3.0 tag?

Comment: runtime error but I fixed it now. I am using beans for different related service inside same project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to just call web service as normal Java class.

```
Customer service = new Customer();
service.getData();
```